# "Undefined is not a function" in jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a plugin in jQuery, but I am getting "undefined is not a function" in this part:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.build = function(options){
        var settings = $.extend({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            type: 0
        }, options);

        $.post("/build", { x: settings.x, y: settings.y, type: settings.type}, function(data) {
            // Return JSON array
            if(data['doBuild'] == 'true') {
                this.append("<div class='item' style='left:"+settings.x+"px; top:"+settings.y+"px;'></div>"); // ERROR ON THIS LINE
            }
        },'json');  

        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

I think that it has to do with the 'this' statement, but I don't understand the error. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` references [the `jqXHR` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) within `$.post`'s callback. It looks like you just need to save a reference to your outer `this`:

```
    var that = this;
    $.post("/build", { x: settings.x, y: settings.y, type: settings.type}, function(data) {
        // Return JSON array
        if(data['doBuild'] == 'true') {
            that.append("<div class='item' style='left:"+settings.x+"px; top:"+settings.y+"px;'></div>");
        }
    },'json');
```

or you can use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
    $.post("/build", { x: settings.x, y: settings.y, type: settings.type}, $.proxy(function(data) {
        // Return JSON array
        if(data['doBuild'] == 'true') {
            this.append("<div class='item' style='left:"+settings.x+"px; top:"+settings.y+"px;'></div>");
        }
    }, this),'json');
```

Comment: I suspected that! I just didn't know how to reference the outer 'this'... I should have taught about saving it to a variable. Thanks, I will try it now!